# Populate Swift array with JSON array

Tags: swift

Fairly new to Swift and trying to figure out how to populate an Swift array with the values of my JSON array.

In my class I define the following value to hold the values for the x-axis of my chart.

```
var xVal: [String]!
```

Below I'm trying to kick out the static array and replace it with data from the JSON file. `xVal` tries to accesses the JSON file, `yVal` is static and works just fine. `xVal` give the following error: `Cannot subscript a value of type 'JSON' with an index of type 'String'`

```
xVal = dataStatistics[indexPath.section]["xval"]
let yVal = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0]

setChart(xVal, values: yVal)
```

This is how the JSON file is structured:

```
{
  "statistics": [
   {
        "title": "Title of chart 1",
        "description": "Chart one contains data of the last year",
        "xval": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
        "yval": [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0]
   }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using `SwiftyJSON`?

Comment: @BobWassermann can you show how you parse json value using the swiftyjson please...

Comment: @RameshVel https://gist.github.com/BobWassermann/b46b6734734aaaf227b30a5c396bfe15

Comment: I think you are only missing a "cast" here. Try: xVal = dataStatistics[indexPath.section]["xval"] as! [String]

Comment: @t4nhpt gives `Cast from 'JSON' to unrelated type '[String]' always fails` error

Answer (score 0):

Based on the input json data, i assume the `swiftyjson` parses `statistics` to another json type. so can you try this

```
let stats = dataStatistics[indexPath.section].dictionaryValue
xval = stats["xval"]
```

see if that works

Comment: Tried `xVal = dataStatistics[indexPath.section]["xval"].dictionaryValue`, but resulted in a `Cannot assign value of type '[String : JSON]' to type '[String!]'` error

Comment: You used wrong way with @RameshVel answer :D. You should not assign the dictionary get from `dictionaryValue` to your 'xVal` variable. You have to create a new variable to store it before get subvalue and assign to xVal.

Comment: It looks like this: `xVal = dataStatistics[indexPath.section].dictionaryValue["xval"]`

Comment: @t4nhpt I see, used it like RameshVel explained now. Getting the same error. Same error for your snippet.

Comment: Try add `.string` to get string value from `JSON`. So, second line of @RameshVel answer will be: `xVal = stats["xval"].string

Comment: @t4nhpt Getting close. Getting `Value of optional type 'JSON?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`, if I change the last line to `xVal = stats["xval"]!.stringValue` I get the `Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type '[String]!'` error

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there is a better way, but this code should work for you:

```
        var xVal: [String] = []
        let stats = dataStatistics[indexPath.row]["xval"]
        if let array = stats.array {
            for json in array {
                xVal.append(json.string!)
            }
            print(xVal)
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. `Ambiguous reference to member 'stat'`

Comment: Getting `Expected '{' to start the body of for-each loop` and `Use of unresolved identifier 'json'` now

Comment: Sorry, I am back to code Objective C some nearly day, so forgot the Swift for loop, haha. Why don't you change it to make it work. Just need to change `AnyObject json` to 'json: AnyObject`

Comment: No worries man. I did the adjustment, and get this error `Type 'Element' (aka '(String, JSON)') does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'`